# Referencing Aeronautical Information Manual in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

what would be the correct type of reference for federal publications such as the Aeronautical Information Manual from FAA or the Federal Radionavigation Plan from the Department of Defense? I thought of using the @periodical biblatex type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific entry type for government publications. The best entry type to choose will depend on the output you expect and to a not insignificant degree also on the style you are using.

That said, in the two cases mentioned `@periodical` does not appear to be the ideal choice, because `@periodical` refers to complete issues of a journal or magazine and the two examples don't appear to be journal-like (i.e. they do not consist of articles written by different authors and do not appear to be subdivided into volumes and issue numbers).

I'd try (roughly in that order)

- `@manual`,
- `@report` and
- `@book`

but if none of these work for you there is always

- `@misc`.

Refer to the [`biblatex` manual (§2.1.1 *Regular Types*, pp. 8-13 in v3.16)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for a list of supported fields for each type in the standard model.